# Save editor's value in user meta and retrieve it

Tags: wordpress

I am making user meta fields. I have to implement a field named `business_profile` and implement editor on it. I have implemented the editor but I can't seem to either save its value or retrieve it. Below is my code.

```
<tr>
    <th>
        <label for="address">Business Profile</label></th>
    <td><?php
        $content = get_the_author_meta('business_profile', $user->ID);
        $editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';

        wp_editor($content, $editor_id);
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And for update:

```
update_usermeta($user_id, 'business_profile', $_POST['business_profile']);
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: what is 'editor' is that a text-editor or your profile name ?

Comment: I beleive it should be `update_usermeta($user_id, 'business_profile', $_POST['mycustomeditor']);`

Comment: I think you need something like this: $content = esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'business_profile', $user->ID ) );

Comment: Thankyou @ObmerkKronen, it worked for me.

Comment: @AliZia You are welcome , so I would post it like an answer so you can accept it and mark it as closed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should read

```
update_usermeta($user_id, 'business_profile', $_POST['mycustomeditor']);
```

since `mycustomeditor` is the `$editor_id` than this is how the $`_POST` variable would be named .

`business_profile` on the other hand is just the `meta_data` for user  or `user_meta` name .

It appears you just confused the two .